# Drawing Simple Charts in Power BI Not Working

Tags: powerbi

newbie to Power BI and mystified by what is going wrong...

I have an Excel table including anonymised pupil names and the grade they got for GCSE.  There is a second table with the names of the Grades - i.e. 'Grade 1', 'Grade 2' and so on.

The first thing I want to do is a simple column chart using the name along the bottom and a count of the number of each grade as the vertical bar.

I have ended up working with just text (i.e. 'Grade 1') as first off, Power BI kept on summing the data, even when I worked out how to turn off autosum.

But I still end up with the same problem - Labels along the bottom are correct, but I just get bars that are 9 units high - the number of grades.

I am obviously making a rooky error - but been playing with this for an hour and can't get past it!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu39O.png)

Count of Act - should be the number of each grade
Grade - displaying correctly

Changing whether data is summed or not.  Not using the labels. Originally using the number of the grade and then converting to 'Grade x'

Many thanks for any help!

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I would do is make sure there's a relationship between your Grades table (StudentID, CourseName, GradeKey) and the lookup table (GradeKey, GradeText) on the matching GradeKey columns.

Then I would create a *measure* in the Grades table,

```
Frequency:= COUNTROWS('Grades')
```

(You don't want a calculated column here - doesn't do what you want). Then you add a bar chart to your design surface and put GradeText on the X-axis and then Frequency on values.

Comment: Thank you, this was super-helpful, sorry it took a while to reply!

Comment: Not that I would notice, I was gone hiking all week. Glad it helped!